# Open chrome://settings from a standard webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using `getUserMedia` to access the visitor's webcam, but if the visitor denies access, they will never be asked again.

Detecting that is easy enough (access is denied almost instantly when requested). So when it is blocked, I want to direct the user to `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream` so that they can change the setting (I'll be using browser detection to tailor this link for each browser). But a simple link makes Chrome unhappy:

> Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream

I've also tried various JavaScript-based methods with the same result, and found several sources on the internet quoting `chrome.tabs.create` as an option for extensions (but this isn't an extension so `chrome.tabs` isn't available).

I have 2 questions. The first is simple curiosity; why is this blocked? (what would the risk be from allowing it?). And the main question is: can I get around this restriction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't do this.

Chrome doesn't want to let websites trick inexperienced users into changing Chrome settings.

Answer (score 10):

You can't nor should you. Instead, instruct the user what those settings are and what he needs to do to change them.

A simple click left of the address bar (in the omnibar of Chrome) can be used to change that setting as well.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en

[image]

Comment: Chrome doesn't even let you click on `chrome://` links from external webpages.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I might try showing an arrow pointing to that, if I can find a way to guess where it is. Annoyingly, it still says "Ask by default" if the user blocked it during the same visit, which makes changing it rather unintuitive. There's also the camera icon on the right of the address bar which lets the user change this, but that's even more prone to moving around.

Comment: maybe a screenshot would work just fine?