# Access chrome browser to settings (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any way to access the chrome settings by javascript?
(for example, access the advanced settings of the browser (specifically, to the system settings)).
I know that javascript can enable access to the chrome history.

Thanks in advance,
Dani.

Comment: Take a look at the *[Javascript APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)*. This is for apps, however. It won't be possible to use that API on a regular website.

Comment: I hope not. Talk about a security nightmare. For a website, it can not touch it, for plug-ins you have access.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Open chrome://settings from a standard webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337645/open-chrome-settings-from-a-standard-webpage).

Looks like the answer to your question is "no", due to security issues.