# Is it possible to enable cookies of browsers like chrome or firefox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser

I have a website that depends completely on sessions and I store them in cookies.

So it is necessary that cookies of browser is enabled.

Now I was able to check if cookies are enabled in the browser using java-script like this:

```
if (!navigator.cookieEnabled)
{
    //Display an warning message asking users to enable the cookies.
}
```

But what if user doesn't have knowledge where to find an option to enable cookies in browser.

So I would like to provide a button inside warning message to enable cookies of browser using java-script on button click.

Does browsers give this kind of write functionality to java-script?

Comment: check below seems not allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337645/open-chrome-settings-from-a-standard-webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't enable this using javascript for a security reason. There are good reasons for not allowing that.

There are some other alternatives if you're willing to consider. i.e. passing session id in the url, storing a session id in the localStorage or the modern approach is to go with JWT token.